# What is in a new terminal window's command history?

Tags: bash, command-history

If I open a terminal window (Gnome terminal 3.6.2) and type a command, say `echo "hello"`, then open a new terminal window and type `<Ctrl>Rhello`, I might expect to be able to dig this command out of the history.

But my newly-typed command does not appear at the `` (reverse-i-search)`': `` prompt.

But some commands from *some* terminal *do* appear in the search.

So how does my Linux (Mint 17) decide which terminals' commands should appear in which other terminals' search histories?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Terminal application itself has no relation to the feature you describe. It's important and very useful to understand that all terminal does is the text input and output rest is done in *shell*. Terminal only redirects your keypresses to program running in terminal, displays output generated by that program and able to inform that program about terminal resizes. It is important to understand that because you need to know what should you configure to change behavior.

In absolute majority of cases, default shell in Linux is *bash*, and that is *bash* who does react on your ctrl-R, and all other things you do in terminal window.

Feature you talking about is bash history. There are lot of options how and when bash reads and writes history. By default, bash appends history to history file on exit from the shell, so while you typing in one shell this commands would never appear in history of other shells.

You can save after each command you typed if you add:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a"
```

to your ~/.bashrc file.

You can also reload after each command:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -r"
```

but I don't recommend that because it makes more sense to dedicate each console for particular task and have history for that particular task till exit.

Comment: Although the question is about the Bourne Again shell, as implied by the prompt text that is quoted, note that this answer is not a truism for all shells and is specific to the Bourne Again shell.  The Z Shell has a shared history capability, for example.  Also note that "default shell" is better phrased as default _interactive login_ shell.  Ubuntu and Debian point `/bin/sh` (being one plausible interpretation of "default shell") at the Debian Almquist Shell, and have done for a number of years, for example.

Comment: Without doubt, it's possible to provide a lot of interesting details here, but I deliberately decided to not confuse requester with such details, that would only confuse him.

Comment: Those aren't just interesting details.  Those are corrections to _false statements_ in your answer.  The _default shell_, in all Unix and GNU/Linux installations is _always_ `/bin/sh` not `bash`.   Your answer would be correct to say something like: "`bash` is the default _interactive_ shell on most GNU/Linux installations, including Mint."

Comment: Actually, your comment is *false statement*. There is no such term as *default shell* in POSIX, you just *invented* it and decided that everyone should follow your *terminology*. As there is no other kind of *default shell* in UNIX other than *interactive* I have a right to skip that word without making whole answer wrong. I am *not alone* using *default shell* in this *correct* meaning, and anyone can easily check that using google. Example is the official FreeBSD documentation https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/articles/linux-users/shells.html.

Comment: The FreeBSD docs support my previous statement: `Bash is not included in the default installation` and `FreeBSD uses ... sh(1) as the default user shell.`  Every POSIX compliant installation contains `/bin/sh`. Some do not include `bash` .  Among the reasons: on Debian-based distros  `bash` is 9 times larger than the `/bin/sh`. From the `bash` man page:  `BUGS It's too big and too slow.`  Programs written using `bash` extensions will not run on some POSIX compliant default installations.

Comment: My point is that FreeBSD doc doesn't say it is 'default *interactive* shell' it says 'default *user* shell' or just 'default shell' (see section header), i.e. my terminology is consistent with that. My statement is that *default shell* in Linux in absolute majority of cases is bash, and that is correct. No talks about bash size, extensions, POSIX compatibility or /bin/sh link. No talks about default scripts interpreter or frequently used interpreters.

Answer (score -1):

Since you're on Mint, we'll assume that you're running `bash` as your shell.

The reason you don't see recently typed commands from other windows is because `bash` maintains a history list in memory for the currently running process, and a different history list on disk for saving history between sessions.

When your interactive `bash` shell starts up, it reads your history file (`~/.bash_history` by default) into the runtime history list for the running shell process.  As you type new commands, they are appended only into the history list of that process, not the history file on disk.

Likewise, the `bash` process writes it history list to the history file on disk before exiting.

If you have commands in one terminal window (T1) that you would like to access in another window, (T2) you can do this:

```
T1> history -a  # append history lines from this session to the history file

T2> history -r  # read the history file and append contents to the history list
```

After running the above commands in different `bash` consoles, you should be able to find the commands from T1 in the history list of T2.

There are many environment variables and options in `bash` to affect the history list behavior. Find more details from the `bash` built-in `help` command: `help history`.  There's even more on the `bash` man page (`man bash`) and in the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html).

Comment: -1 because answer is exactly same as my answer above, just made later.

Comment: _Exactly_?  This answer doesn't contain anything about PROMPT_COMMAND (why show an example of something you don't recommend?) and your answer never mentioned when `bash` normally reads the history file.  The questioner didn't ask about how to save/restore history after each command, so I wanted to give an answer direct to the question, with references to the sources. Sorry you didn't like it.